# Google cloud - Python automation

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-api-python-client

I would like to know how can I manage data that I can get as an output from gcloud commands embedded in the Python script. For example, I prepared simple script in Python. I am executing it from the Google Cloud Shell Editor. Code looks like below:

```
import subprocess

project = "gcloud info --format='value(config.project)'"
subprocess.call(project, shell=True)
subprocess.run(["gcloud config set project projectID"], shell=True)
result = subprocess.run(["gcloud compute instances os-inventory list-instances"], shell=True)
print(result)
```

As an output in the terminal I can see list of VMs. I would like to filter out only VMs with a specific property, name or IP number. How can I manage these output, the class of that variable `result` is `<class 'subprocess.CompletedProcess'>`.

Script output looks like below:

```
NAME           ZONE            MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP      STATUS
server00       europe-west2-c  e2-medium                  10.x.x.x     x.x.x.x           RUNNING
server01       europe-west2-c  e2-medium                  10.x.x.x     x.x.x.x           RUNNING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `result.stdout`.

You may need to add `capture_output=True` to the subprocess.run call as well. So do:

```
subprocess.run(["gcloud config set project projectID"], capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
```

That will give you the stdout text which you can then split on newlines, iterate over the array created, filter on whatever you need, etc.

For filtering, you could either do it on the subprocess command, or post processing. So for example, if you wanted to only see resulting VMs that are in the us-central1 region, you could change your subprocess command from:

`["gcloud config set project projectID"]`

to

`["gcloud config set project projectID | grep us-central1"]`

Alternately, to post-process you could do:

```
project = "gcloud info --format='value(config.project)'"
subprocess.call(project, shell=True)
subprocess.run(["gcloud config set project projectID"], shell=True)
result = subprocess.run(["gcloud compute instances os-inventory list-instances"], shell=True)

arr = result.stdout.split("\n")
for line in arr:
  if "us-central1" in line:
    print(line)
```

Comment: I modified the code, `p = subprocess.run(["gcloud compute instances os-inventory list-instances --format json"], capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
result = p.stdout
print(result)`, but how to parse that json output?

Comment: Edited my answer to be more specific about how you'd do it.

Comment: Hi, Thank You, that works fine, but how to get into json structure, for example how to get the value like: `print(result['name'])` to get all values with a json key name: `name`. I would like to rather parse json file.

Comment: You should have it if you've added the `--format=json`, but it might be in the wrong place from the code you have in the comment above. It should go after the gcloud command, not after the group...so like this: `["gcloud --format=json compute instances os-inventory list-instances"]`

Answer (score 0):

Could you edit the question and show a example output so its easier to make a answer without setting up gcloud.

Because I don't know how the output looks like I can't give a exact answer about how to filter out.
But if you would want to get the output from the "gcloud compute instances os-inventory list-instances" you would do like this:

```py
import subprocess

project = "gcloud info --format='value(config.project)'"
subprocess.call(project, shell=True)
subprocess.run(["gcloud config set project projectID"], shell=True)
p = subprocess.Popen(["gcloud", "compute instances os-inventory list-instances"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()

print(out)
```

Comment: I have just added the output I can see in the terminal in Google portal.

Comment: Hi, your code does not work in my env, I am getting an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gcloud ': 'gcloud '`

Comment: change gcloud to the path to the gcloud executable and it should work

Comment: What do you mean by that - " gcloud executable", location where I have my .py file?

Comment: No where the application "gcloud" that you are executing is located, if you are on linux it may be in /usr/bin