# gcloud command - set variable for project to run gcloud command on multiple project ids

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am very new to gcloud command line and new to scripting altogether. I'm cleaning up a GCP org with multiple stray projects. I am trying to run a gcloud command to find the creator of all my projects so I can reach out to each project creator and ask them to clean up a few things.

I found a command to search logs for a project and find the original project creator, provided the project isn't older than 400 days.

```bash
gcloud logging read --project [PROJECT] \
  --order=asc --limit=1 \
  --format='table(protoPayload.methodName, protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail)'
```

My problem is this: I have over 300 projects in my org currently. I have a .csv of all project names and IDs via (gcloud projects list).

Using the above command. How can I make [project] a variable and call/import the project name field from my .csv as the variable.

What I hope to accomplish is this: The gcloud command line provided the output for each project name  in the .csv file and outputs it all to a another .csv file. I hope this all made sense.

Thanks.

I haven't tried anything yet. I don't want to run the same command for each of the 300 projects manually.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is probably easily done in Python. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68178892/google-cloud-python-automation) answer is quite close to your use case. Basically you need to read your .csv file with something like Pandas for example, and then run the `gcloud` command you've provided as a subprocess in the script

Comment: Thank bhito. Unfortunately, I am very new to the scripting world and have no experience with python.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your input `.csv` (with fake data)? And what you'd expect your output `.csv` file to look like? I'll try to put something together for you

Answer (score 0):

I have put together this bash script, however I've been unable to properly test as I don't currently have access to any GCP project, but hopefully it will work.

Input:
This is how the CSV file should look like

```
| ids  |
|------|
| 1234 |
| 4567 |
| 7890 |
| 0987 |
```

Output: what the script will generate

```
| project_id | owner |
|------------|-------|
| 1234       | john  |
| 4567       | doe   |
| 7890       | test  |
| 0987       | user  |
```

```bash
#! /bin/bash
touch output.csv
echo "project_id, owner;" >>> output.csv
while IFS="," read -r data
do
  echo "Fetching project creator for: $data"
  creator=$(gcloud logging read --project ${data} --order=asc --limit=1 --format='table(protoPayload.methodName, protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail)')
  echo "${data},${creator};" >>> output.csv
done < <(cut -d ";" -f1 input.csv | tail -n +2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below script can be used to achieve the desired result.

```
for PROJECT in $(gcloud projects list --format='value(PROJECT_ID)')
do
gcloud logging read "protoPayload.methodName=CreateProject AND resource.type=project AND severity=NOTICE" --project $PROJECT --order=asc --limit=1 --format='csv[no-heading](resource.labels.project_id,protoPayload.methodName, protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail)'>>owner.csv
done
```

make sure to delete the **owner.csv** file before re-running the script